# Εlevate GITHUB_TOKEN's permissions in Github Actions

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, workflow

Each workflow run has access to a scoped `GITHUB_TOKEN` that has specific permissions.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#permissions-for-the-github_token), the **default** permissions for `pull_requests` is `read/write`.

If there is a branch protection rule (PR review required before merging), can the `GITHUB_TOKEN` permissions be elevated to the point it overrides such a rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - in case you need different permissions, you should use PAT instead (Personal Access Token).